# Rsync on multiple hosts in parallel

Tags: linux, bash, rsync, xargs, gnu-parallel

I need to send frequently a lot of files to a multiple hosts and is crucial to be fast and I want it to do it in parallel.

how can I run in a bash script a parallel rsync to multiple hosts?

now the script looks like this

```
   for i in ${listofhosts[*]}
   do
   rsync -rv --checksum  folder/ -e "ssh -i rsa_key -o 
   StrictHostKeyChecking=no" user@$i:/var/test/folder --delete  || 
   exit 1
   done
```

LE: I'm thinking of something with **GNU Parallel** or **xargs** but I don't know how to use them in this situation

Comment: I don't think it's possible to keep the `|| exit 1` condition while launching `rsync`s in //. Also, you may want to put a limit on how many `rsync`s will run at the same time.

Comment: I can give up to `|| exit 1`.

Comment: I think of **GNU Parallel** or **xargs** but I don't know how to use them in this situation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With just a shell script,

```sh
#!/bin/bash
procs=()
for i in "${listofhosts[@]}"; do  # notice syntax fixes
  rsync -rv --checksum  folder/ -e "ssh -i rsa_key -o 
   StrictHostKeyChecking=no" user@$i:/var/test/folder --delete &
  procs+=($!)
done
for proc in "${procs[@]}"; do
  wait "$proc"
done
```

The obvious drawback is that you can't cancel the others as soon as one of them fails. If you really have "a lot" of hosts, this will probably saturate your network bandwidth to the point where you regret asking about how to do this.

With `xargs`, you can limit how many instances you run:

```
# probably better if you have the hosts in a file instead of an array actually,
# and simply run xargs <filename -P 17 -n 1 ...
printf '%s\n' "${listofhosts[@]}" |
xargs -P 17 -n 1 sh -c 'rsync -rv --checksum  folder/ -e "ssh -i rsa_key -o 
   StrictHostKeyChecking=no" user@"$0":/var/test/folder --delete || exit 1'
```

Perhaps notice how we sneakily smuggle in the host in `$0`. You could equivalently but *slightly* less obscurely populate `$0` with a dummy string and use `$1`, but it doesn't really make a lot of difference here.

The `-P 17` says to run a maximum of 17 processes in parallel (obviously, tweak to your liking), and `-n 1` says to only run one instance of the command line at a time.  `xargs` still does not offer a way to interrupt the entire batch if one of the processes fails, and only reports back summaric result codes (like, the exit code from `xargs` will be non-zero if at least one of the processes failed).

If you want to keep track of which ones failed, perhaps have the script print that out to a separate file.

```sh
rm -r failures.txt
printf '%s\n' "${listofhosts[@]}" |
xargs -P 17 -n 1 sh -c 'rsync -rv --checksum  folder/ -e "ssh -i rsa_key -o 
   StrictHostKeyChecking=no" user@"$0":/var/test/folder --delete && exit 0
    echo "$0" failed: $? >>failures.txt'
```

If this is for subsequent processing, probably write the results in machine readable form to the file - maybe simply `echo $? $0` so you can loop over it with

```sh
while IFS='' read -r exitcode hostname; do
   : 
done <failures.txt
```

or perhaps a standard format like CSV or JSON or etc.

Comment: `parallel` is more versatile and elegant, but unfortunately, I'm still not familiar enough with it to competently include it in my answer.

Comment: Thank you very much! Is there a way to save the output of xargs and test it for errors? I need to know if the information arrived on all hosts

Comment: Examining the output is not particularly reliable. Perhaps save the hostname - exit code pair for each host and examine that.

Comment: How can I do that?

Comment: See updated answer now

Comment: Thanks a lot! You saved me!

Answer (score 1):

With GNU Parallel you would do something like this:

```
doit() {
  i="$1"
  rsync -rv --checksum  folder/ -e "ssh -i rsa_key -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no" user@$i:/var/test/folder --delete || 
    exit 1
}
export -f doit
parallel doit ::: ${listofhosts[@]}
```

May I suggest spending 20 minutes on reading chapter 1+2 (and possibly chapter 5): https://doi.org/10.5281/zenodo.1146014

You command line will love you for it.